# Managing loops in a video game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, events, actionscript

I'm trying to make a small game, and this requires using several "loops". In my case, the user is first presented with two fields and a "Connect" button. Once he clicks the button, the fields and buttons are removed, and the game moves to another screen which is containing a single "disconnect" button, that'll take him to the first screen again. This is my naive implementation of it (I simplified it a lot) :

```
package Application {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.controls.TextArea;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        var IPField:TextArea;
        var PortField:TextArea;
        var disconnectButton:Button;
        var nickField:TextArea;
        var passField:TextArea;
        var loginButton:Button;
        var network:NetworkHandler;

        public function Main() {
            IPField = new TextArea();
            PortField = new TextArea();
            disconnectButton = new Button();

            // Snipped : positioning the Buttons and TextAreas

            network = new NetworkHandler(this.stage, IPField, PortField);
            network.addEventListener("connection_opened", onConnect);
            network.addEventListener("connection_error", onError);
            disconnectButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, network.doConnect);

            addChild(IPField);
            addChild(PortField);
            addChild(disconnectButton);
        }

        private function onConnect(e:Event):void {
            removeChild(IPField);
            removeChild(PortField);
            removeChild(disconnectButton);
            disconnectButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, network.doConnect);
            network.removeEventListener("connection_opened", onConnect);
            network.removeEventListener("connection_error", onError);

            network.addEventListener("connection_closed", returnToConnect);
            network.addEventListener("connection_error", returnToConnect);
            disconnectButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, network.doDisconnect);
            addChild(disconnectButton);
        }

        private function returnToConnect(e:Event):void {
            loginButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,network.doConnect);
            removeChild(disconnectButton);
            network.removeEventListener("connection_closed", returnToConnect);
            network.removeEventListener("connection_error", returnToConnect);

            disconnectButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, network.doConnect);
            network.addEventListener("connection_opened", onConnect);
            network.addEventListener("connection_error", onError);
            addChild(IPField);
            addChild(PortField);
            addChild(disconnectButton);
        }

        private function onError(e:Event):void {
            // Error management
        }
    }
}
```

For the record, NetworkManager is a class I designed, and that basically manages the connection, dispatching events whenever the connection is established/closed/dropped.

So, I have two questions :

- Isn't the way I used to implement this recursive? Meaning, if someone where to press Connect, disconnect, connect, etc., would it eventually lead to a stack overflow? (Assuming that there are more buttons on the page, things taking a lot of memory, etc)
- What is the best way to implement this? In the end, there will be several more "loops" in the game, so i'm not sure whether this is a good solution or not. What's commonly used by game devs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not recursive, because you are using events and your listeners do not make calls to each other. And yes, this is normal model to use event listeners. You may even retain event listeners in place, because they will not trigger if the object is not on the stage. The only thing I'd change is grouping, that is, use container `Sprite` objects to place a set of nested scenery in a single `addChild()` with a restriction if necessary, so that you won't get two different scenes on your screen at once.

PS: Use `TextField` instead of `TextArea`, if you are planning them to receive one-line input from user. Set the text field type to `input` and watch the show.

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of using `Sprite` objects. How can I make them contain several objects? I was also using `TextField`, but I was having issues with applying `TextFormat` on them, ifI recall correctly. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: You create a `Sprite`, then call its `addChild()` with whatever objects you want it to contain. A `Sprite` is like a box, that can be opened when placed to stage. `var menu:Sprite=new Sprite(); menu.addChild(newGameButton); menu.addChild(loadGameButton); ...etc addChild(menu);`

Comment: You will also be able to move, rotate or scale the entirety of a sprite without its contents to change their relative position, this sometimes has a great use. If you plan to do so, then you will have to place sprite's contents at coordinates relative to that sprite's turning point (anchor point, (0,0) ) so that you won't need to devise custom rotation, and also the sprite should be properly placed on screen so that its entire contents are visible (or the part you want visible will be visible).

Comment: Won't retaining the event listeners in place cause additional lag/memory usage, even if the object is not on stage?

Comment: Lag? No, because while the object is not in the display list, it is not checked whether it has event listeners for any mouse, keyboard or frame events. UI events only roam the display list. Memory usage? Actually, negligible, because having an event listener removed only affects some internal structures for a couple of bytes, while an extra object of any kind consumes much more. But, having many objects with listeners attached *is* causing lag plus memory usage. You here are having one of each button, without code to make more than one, so leave them be.